# Java Swing customize SpinnerNumberModel

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I want to change the SpinnerNumberModel of a JSpinner in a seperate class (e.g. MyNumberSpinner)

I use these values: 10(startvalue), 1(minimum), 500(maximum) and 10 (steps).

Now I want it to go to the minimum(1) when im <11 and press the down arrow, but when i press the up arrow from the minimum(1) i want it to go to 10.

can u guys help me ?

Comment: Please spell out a little clearer exactly what you're trying to do, what you've tried in code so far, etc... Have you created your own SpinnerModel one that extends AbstractSpinnerModel?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have your read the JavaDocs on these model classes?

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to use something that I just learned about by reading through the API: the [SpinnerListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerListModel.html). This is a model which will accept any `List<T>` object, including for your purposes, a `List<Integer>`.

For example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerListModel;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class SpinnerNumberFun2 {

   private static final int MAX_VALUE = 500;
   private static final int STEP = 10;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<Integer> dataList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      dataList.add(1);
      int index = 0;
      while (index < MAX_VALUE) {
         index += STEP;
         dataList.add(index);
      }

      SpinnerListModel myListModel = new SpinnerListModel(dataList);
      final JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(myListModel);
      spinner.setValue(dataList.get(1));

      spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent cEvt) {
            int value = ((Integer)spinner.getValue()).intValue();
            System.out.println("Value is: " + value);
         }
      });

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, spinner);
   }
}
```